# Grails app on CloudFoundry will not restart

Tags: tomcat, grails, cloud-foundry

I'm using STS to deploy a Grails app to CloudFoundry.  Everything had been going fine, making edits and doing "Update and Restart."  All of a sudden, I started having problems where the app does not restart successfully.  Here is what the log shows:

```
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:31 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-6401
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 380 ms
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:31 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm setContainer
INFO: Set JAAS app name Catalina
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager@2ff7ac92] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [com.lossless.S2Role.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.data] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [quartzScheduler_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [quartzScheduler_Worker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [quartzScheduler_Worker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [quartzScheduler_Worker-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [quartzScheduler_Worker-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [quartzScheduler_Worker-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [quartzScheduler_Worker-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [quartzScheduler_Worker-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [quartzScheduler_Worker-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [quartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Actual transaction active]) and a value of type [java.lang.Boolean] (value [true]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Transactional resources]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@19129103=org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@1251dee1, org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@21faa3c5=org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@3cff8f2c}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Current transaction name]) and a value of type [java.lang.String] (value [lossless.MarketScannerJob.execute]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Current aspect-driven transaction]) and a value of type [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.TransactionInfo] (value [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; '']) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Oct 10, 2012 2:18:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.springframework.core.NamedThreadLocal] (value [Transaction synchronizations]) and a value of type [java.util.LinkedHashSet] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
....
Stopping Tomcat because the context stopped.
```

I tried deleting the app, but that didn't help.  I tried deleting the app and the database, but that didn't help.  What finally worked last night was to create a new database with a different name.  Today, I'm back to the same problem again.

I'm not certain when the problem appeared, but it *might* be related to when I added the Quartz plugin and created a job.

Obviously, I can't keep recreating a new database every time I make a change to my application.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks for any advice!  This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was getting this exception during Bootstrap execution, due to some cascading issues.

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

Part of the problem was that I could not see the error.  A very useful flag for finding such issues is failOnError:

```
o.save(failOnError:true)
```

Once I added that flag to my save() calls, I could see the exception.  And once I got rid of the exception, my app started running again, and I am now able to Update and Restart, as well.

And here's another handy tip for working with CloudFoundry.  These commands let you list the log files:

```
vmc files <appname> logs
vmc files <appname> tomcat/logs
```

These commands let you view the contents of the log files:

```
vmc files <appname> logs/stdout.log
vmc files <appname> logs/stderr.log
vmc files <appname> tomcat/logs/localhost.2012-10-11.log
vmc files <appname> tomcat/logs/catalina.2012-10-11.log
```

I hope this helps someone.  It sure helped me.

Comment: I just ran into this same issue again, and even wiping out the app and service and starting clean would not resolve it.  In digging into the exception I found in logs/stdout.log, something just didn't add up.  Which led me to do a CLEAN in STS.  Once I did that, the redeploy finally worked as expected all along.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with Grails and the quartz plugin.

When I installed the Plugin via `grails install quatz-plugin` command line, it created a folder names Jobs under grails-app and added it's sources there, but STS didn't recognizd that as a valid folder for source and it crashed my app every single time I tried to use it

In my case the Job folder under

```
grails-app/jobs
```

was not listed as a source folder in STS, so the application was dying when the Job was requested, which was at the app start.

Comment: No, the app starts fine on my machine, and the job definitely runs.  (But I didn't give you the -1.)  :-)

Comment: But you *do* have a point.  This same thing did happen to me, and it never occurred to me to add it as a source folder.  I've simply navigated to it since I've realized it was under grails-apps.  But now I'm going to add it to the source folders list.